# Do taylor series smooth functions of power series with finite convergence radius at every point converge to itself on every point of real line

Tags: real-analysis, power-series, taylor-expansion, uniform-convergence, analytic-functions

Let $g$ be a smooth function with all n-th derivatives satisfying $\vert g^{n}(x)\vert\leq \frac{C n!}{\rho^n}$ where $\rho$ is a fixed number for all $x\in R$. $f(x)=\sum_n \frac{g^{(n)}(0)}{n!}(x)^n$. Is this series converges to $f(x)$ uniformly on $R$? I am looking for a counter example as I do not think it holds.

Comment: How does $\rho$ compare with $1$?

Comment: @Ian $\rho$ will be provide a estimation of radius of convergence. However, there is no further specification of $\rho$'s size. I guess $\rho$ can be greater than 1 or less than 1.